# How does one pass nullptr through P/Invoke declared with a StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

Consider a typical P/Invoke declaration like this:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool LookupAccountName(
string SystemName,
string accountName,
IntPtr pSid,
ref uint cbSid,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder ReferencedDomainName,
ref uint ReferencedDomainNameCount,
out SID_NAME_USE SIDUse);
```

[MSDN documentation for LookupAccountName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379159.aspx) says that `pSid` and `ReferencedDomainName` may be `nullptr` if the customer wishes. Passing `nullptr` for `pSid` is easy; just pass `IntPtr.Zero`. But what should one pass for a `StringBuilder`?

I don't want to pass an empty `StringBuilder`, because I don't want this call to fail with `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`.

Comment: @pm100: That fails because `IntPtr` is not convertible to `StringBuilder`.

Comment: then declare a second import that takes inptr in that place

Comment: @pm100: Can't do that. (Other pieces of code currently use this call and I don't want to fix that up everywhere)

Comment: other answer is good. But FYI you can create a second dllimport for the same function but with a different name so that you can fiddle with the param definitons (EntryPoint=xxx)

Comment: @pm100: That seems like it'd be a massive hack :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just pass `null` for this parameter; it will be marshalled as a null pointer.